# how do i get my forms to submit into a function - HTML

Tags: html

my code is supposed to get the input of the users address ad then run it through the function "newContact" however i get errors constantly and i was wondering if anyone knows why.

```
<html>
<body>

    <div>
      <form id="adContact">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        <label for="numb">Number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="numb" name="numb"><br>
        <label for="adr">Adress:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="adr" name="adr"> <br> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add contact">

      </form>
    </div>

  <script>
    $("#adContact").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $fname = $("#fname");
      var fname = $fname.val();
      var $lname = $("#lname");
      var lname = $lname.val();
      var $numb = $("#numb");
      var numb = $numb.val();
      var $adr = $("#adress");
      var adr = $adr.val();
      newContact(fname, lname, numb, adr);
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72423991/edit) to show specific examples. At first glance it looks like you're failing to include the jQuery library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.